# ASIFormDataRequest has empty POST body

Tags: objective-c, http, macos

I had a working MacOS application that was making a POST to a server. I changed the URL of the POST and things stopped working.

I downloaded Tuffcode (a sniffer), which shows me that when using the new URL, the POST BODY is empty!

```
- (IBAction)grabURLInBackground:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url1"];
    //NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url2"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Language" value:@"en"];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Connection" value:@"keep-alive"];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Cookie" value: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"botcust2=%@", sn]];
    [request setShouldAttemptPersistentConnection:NO];

    [request addPostValue:[input stringValue] forKey:@"input"];
    [input setStringValue:@""];
    [request startAsynchronous];

}
```

Switching from url1 to url2 goes from a well formed POST BODY to an empty POST BODY. How could that be? How can the URL determine what gets sent?
At first I thought it was the new server that did not interpret the POST correctly, but if Tuffcode is correct, the application doesn't even send the data??

Or maybe there is something I don't know about how HTTP works? I am confused...

Some logs:

```
2011-07-29 12:28:36.018 ChatBot[6764:707] [STATUS] Starting asynchronous request <ASIFormDataRequest: 0x10188d420>
2011-07-29 12:28:36.021 ChatBot[6764:6403] 
==== Building an application/x-www-form-urlencoded body ====
input=hello
==== End of application/x-www-form-urlencoded body ====
2011-07-29 12:28:36.027 ChatBot[6764:6403] [CONNECTION] Request <ASIFormDataRequest: 0x10188d420> will not use a persistent connection
2011-07-29 12:28:36.280 ChatBot[6764:6403] [STATUS] Request <ASIFormDataRequest: 0x10188d420> finished uploading data
2011-07-29 12:28:36.374 ChatBot[6764:6403] [STATUS] Request <ASIFormDataRequest: 0x10188d420> received response headers
2011-07-29 12:28:36.375 ChatBot[6764:6403] [STATUS] Request <ASIFormDataRequest: 0x10188d420> finished downloading data (0 bytes)
2011-07-29 12:28:36.376 ChatBot[6764:6403] [STATUS] Request finished: <ASIFormDataRequest: 0x10188d420>
```

Comment: Also note that with an HTML form running in the browser, both URLs work fine

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting the string to null right after you post?

```
[request addPostValue:[input stringValue] forKey:@"input"];
[input setStringValue:@""];
```

It's possible that the compiler is switching the order of those two lines and you are submitting that null string. Why don't you try running it with the 2nd line removed?

Comment: This clears the input in the UI. I tried to remove that line, but it didn't really help. I noticed that sometimes it says "reset by peer", and sometimes the input shows up in the sniffer (with no response). But with the old URL it always works both ways

Answer (score 0):

A little after the fact, but I've just run into something similar. Like you I had a ASIHTTPRequest setup to work with a previous instance of an application but in the new version the POST was empty (no data sent); I knew the server on the other end was working fine (same code, but new hosting/URL) so I knew it couldn't be that.

After playing with it for a bit I remembered that the old URL was submission.php, but this time it was it's own folder (so just /submission/), adding index.php to the end of my new URL magically made things work again; so I guess it just didn't like not having a file at the end of the URL.

tl;dr - make sure your submission URL's end with a file name (ie: index.php or similar)

nbsp